# A program to synchronize the objects of two databases MS Access

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, adodb

I am developing a program in VB 2005 using ADODB.
Consider two MS Access Databases. One with table1 and other with table2, table3.

When we run the program and select the two databases. It will create the table2,table3 of second database into first database.

[Interface Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0cPV.png)

The program can successfully generate a list of tables to be generated. After that I have another function to create "CREATE TABLE" statement.

```
Function CreateCreateTableStatement(ByVal DBPath As String, ByVal TableName As String) As String
        On Error GoTo EndErr
        Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
        Dim TablesSchema, ColumnsSchema, PrimaryKeysSchema As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim tempsql, PrimaryKeyColumn As String
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & DBPath & "';"
        cnn.Mode = ADODB.ConnectModeEnum.adModeShareExclusive
        DoLog("Getting tables list of " & DBPath)
        cnn.Open()
        TablesSchema = cnn.OpenSchema(ADODB.SchemaEnum.adSchemaTables)
        TablesSchema.Filter = "TABLE_NAME = '" & TableName & "'"
        PrimaryKeysSchema = cnn.OpenSchema(ADODB.SchemaEnum.adSchemaPrimaryKeys)
        PrimaryKeysSchema.Filter = "TABLE_NAME = '" & TableName & "'"
        If PrimaryKeysSchema.EOF = False Then PrimaryKeyColumn = PrimaryKeysSchema("COLUMN_NAME").Value
        PrimaryKeysSchema.Close()
        ColumnsSchema = cnn.OpenSchema(ADODB.SchemaEnum.adSchemaColumns)
        ColumnsSchema.Filter = "TABLE_NAME = '" & TableName & "'"
        tempsql = "CREATE TABLE " & TableName & " ("
        Do While Not ColumnsSchema.EOF
            tempsql = tempsql + ColumnsSchema("COLUMN_NAME").Value & " " & DataCodeToName(ColumnsSchema("DATA_TYPE").Value) & " " & " (" & ColumnsSchema("CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH").Value & ") " '& ColumnsSchema("IS_NULLABLE").Value & ColumnsSchema("COLUMN_DEFAULT").Value & ", " & ColumnsSchema("IS_NULLABLE").Value & ", " & DataCodeToName(ColumnsSchema("DATA_TYPE").Value) & ", " & ColumnsSchema("CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH").Value
            If PrimaryKeyColumn = ColumnsSchema("COLUMN_NAME").Value Then tempsql = tempsql + " PRIMARY KEY, " Else tempsql = tempsql + ", "
            ColumnsSchema.MoveNext()
        Loop
        tempsql = tempsql.Substring(0, Len(tempsql) - 2) + ");"
        cnn.Close()
        DoLog("Gotten tables list of " & DBPath)
        Return tempsql
        Exit Function
EndErr:
        cnn.Close()
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
    End Function
```

Output Of the function was before changing it:

```
CREATE TABLE Table2 (Column1 VARCHAR, Column11 UNSIGNED BYTE, Column12 SHORT, Column13 SINGLE, Column14 DOUBLE, Column15 Guid, Column16 NUMERIC, Column2 VARCHAR, Column3 LONG, Column4 DateTime, Column5 CURRENCY, Column6 LONG PRIMARY KEY, Column7 BIT, Column8 BINARY, Column9 VARCHAR);
```

But after executing the SQL, the error "Syntax error in field definition" raised. So I changed the function slightly and added max length as shown in above code. The above code generated SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Table2 (Column1 VARCHAR  (255) , Column11 UNSIGNED BYTE  () , Column12 SHORT  () , Column13 SINGLE  () , Column14 DOUBLE  () , Column15 LONG  () , Column16 DECIMAL  () , Column2 VARCHAR  (0) , Column3 LONG  () , Column4 DateTime  () , Column5 CURRENCY  () , Column6 LONG  ()  PRIMARY KEY, Column7 BIT  (2) , Column8 BINARY  (0) , Column9 VARCHAR  (0) );
```

After generating the above SQL the error was the same.
All I want is just the help about create table statement. Below is the image of Table2, of which the create table statement is.
[Table2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwTvD.png)

Comment: Did some testing. Couldn't get Access to accept the UNSIGNED BYTE type.

Comment: Also doesn't like the parens() after Long, Short, Binary, Bit, Single, Double, Currency. Doesn't like Decimal at all.

Comment: Thank you guys! both of you. It worked. But now I am in another problem. After hard work of complete one day the results told me that the columns created by the query don't has many properties set. So, I have to choose another method for creating table in ms access db using vb 2005.
Any suggestions!!

Comment: `I have to choose another method for creating table in ms access db using vb 2005. Any suggestions`-- Since you are using `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`, you should have the COM reference `Microsoft Office xx.y Access database engine Object Library` available.  Add it.  This will allow you to use Access DAO objects to manipulate the databases (TableDef, Field, Field.Properties) just like you would using Access VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function CreateCreateTableStatement(ByVal DBPath As String, ByVal TableName As String) As String
        'CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE table (field1 type [(size)] [NOT NULL] [WITH COMPRESSION | WITH COMP] [index1] [, field2 type [(size)] [NOT NULL] [index2]
        ' [, …]] [, CONSTRAINT multifieldindex [, …]])
        On Error GoTo EndErr
        Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
        Dim TablesSchema, ColumnsSchema, PrimaryKeysSchema As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim tempsql, PrimaryKeyColumn, ColLen As String
        Dim i As Integer
        cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & DBPath & "';"
        cnn.Mode = ADODB.ConnectModeEnum.adModeShareExclusive
        DoLog("Getting tables list of " & DBPath)
        cnn.Open()
        TablesSchema = cnn.OpenSchema(ADODB.SchemaEnum.adSchemaTables)
        TablesSchema.Filter = "TABLE_NAME = '" & TableName & "'"
        PrimaryKeysSchema = cnn.OpenSchema(ADODB.SchemaEnum.adSchemaPrimaryKeys)
        PrimaryKeysSchema.Filter = "TABLE_NAME = '" & TableName & "'"
        If PrimaryKeysSchema.EOF = False Then PrimaryKeyColumn = PrimaryKeysSchema("COLUMN_NAME").Value
        PrimaryKeysSchema.Close()
        ColumnsSchema = cnn.OpenSchema(ADODB.SchemaEnum.adSchemaColumns)
        ColumnsSchema.Filter = "TABLE_NAME = '" & TableName & "'"
        'ColumnsSchema.Sort = "`ORDINAL_POSITION`"
        tempsql = "CREATE TABLE `" & TableName & "` ("
        Do While Not ColumnsSchema.EOF
            If ColumnsSchema("CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH").Value.ToString = "" Or ColumnsSchema("CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH").Value.ToString = "0" Then ColLen = "" 'Else ColLen = "(" & ColumnsSchema("CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH").Value & ")"
            tempsql = tempsql & "`" & ColumnsSchema("COLUMN_NAME").Value & "` " & DataCodeToName(ColumnsSchema("DATA_TYPE").Value) & " " & ColLen ' & ColumnsSchema("IS_NULLABLE").Value & ColumnsSchema("COLUMN_DEFAULT").Value & ", " & ColumnsSchema("IS_NULLABLE").Value & ", " & DataCodeToName(ColumnsSchema("DATA_TYPE").Value) & ", " & ColumnsSchema("CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH").Value
            If PrimaryKeyColumn = ColumnsSchema("COLUMN_NAME").Value Then tempsql = tempsql + " NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, " Else tempsql = tempsql + ", "
            ColumnsSchema.MoveNext()
        Loop
        tempsql = tempsql.Substring(0, Len(tempsql) - 2) + ");"
        cnn.Close()
        DoLog("Gotten tables list of " & DBPath)
        Return tempsql
        Exit Function
EndErr:
        cnn.Close()
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
    End Function
```

Thank you guys. But Today I discovered the right SQL for creating the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `Table3` (`Column1` VARCHAR , `Column11` BYTE , `Column12` SHORT , `Column13` SINGLE , `Column14` DOUBLE , `Column15` GUID , `Column16` DECIMAL , `Column2` VARCHAR , `Column3` LONG , `Column4` DateTime , `Column5` CURRENCY , `Column6` LONG  NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, `Column7` BIT , `Column8` OLEOBJECT , `Column9` VARCHAR );
```

Everything is working fine, but there are some difference between the table created by above SQL and the one created through MS Access Interface.

Answer (score 0):

Code from my db to create table in backend and edit table properties:

```
If IsNull(Me.tbxTestNum) Then
    MsgBox "Must enter test number.", vbCritical, "Error"
Else
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    'connect to the backend database
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='" & gstrBasePath & "Data\LabData.accdb'"
    'create the test table
    cn.Execute "CREATE TABLE " & Me.tbxTestNum & " (LabNum text(12) PRIMARY KEY Not Null, method text(30) Not Null);"

    'set table link
    Set tdf = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(Me.tbxTestNum)
    tdf.SourceTableName = Me.tbxTestNum
    tdf.Connect = "; DATABASE=" & gstrBasePath & "Data\LabData.accdb"
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append tdf

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM BuildTable;", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic
    Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(gstrBasePath & "Data\LabData.accdb")
    While Not rs.EOF
        If rs!DataField <> "LabNum" And rs!DataField <> "method" Then
            'create field in new table
            cn.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & Me.tbxTestNum & " ADD COLUMN " & _
                        rs!DataField & " " & IIf(rs!DataType = "Boolean", "Bit", rs!DataType) & _
                        IIf(rs!DataType = "Text", "(" & rs!FieldSize & ")", "") & ";"
        End If
        'must use DAO to set AllowZeroLength property, I don't allow zero length fields and Access defaults to Yes
        If rs!DataType = "Text" Then
            'change the AllowZeroLength default Yes to No
            db.TableDefs(Me.tbxTestNum).Fields(rs!DataField).AllowZeroLength = False
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    db.Close

End If
```